# my subclass from UIPopoverBackgroundView can't access UIPopoverBackgroundView's instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I made a class which is subclass of `UIPopoverBackgroundView`:

```
@interface TestPopView : UIPopoverBackgroundView

@end
```

Where i tried access the property `arrowOffset` of `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class.

[image]

but when i implement a method in my subclass ,and i want to access  `arrowOffset` directly (using the form  `_arrowOffset` ,not using `getter&setter`) , the compiler complains "use of undeclared identifier `_arrowOffset`

[image]

what's the reason ,i can't acess the property directy?

Comment: Try super to access.

Comment: i just wanna know why i can't access it directy ? because the variable synthesized is not public ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance variable _arrowOffset is private iVar to superclass and thus us not directly accessible to subclass. You can use getter/setter to use it in subclass, which works.

Comment: thx , i already found the access problem after i post the quesiton , how stupid i am -_-